# How to fetch a specific job from the queue using Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm working with Delayed::Job recently, and I want to find out if there's a specific job is enqueued or not, any idea on that?

Answer (score 1):

The jobs are all written to a table named delayed_jobs, and Delayed::Job is an ActiveRecord class that you can use to query the table. You might want to query the handler column.

I'd recommend against this, however. There's probably a more elegant way to solve the problem.